# How to simultaneously start 2 commands in .bat file at two different paths?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two directories with programs I want to run simultanously:

```
C:\ProgramA\startA.bat
C:\ProgramB\startB.bat
```

How can I have a single bat file that simultaneously run both commands? Note that they should be asynchronous as startA will not 'end' and startB does not end either. They output text in the terminal and hang there.

I want to avoid having to open up one terminal, CD into programA, run the startA.bat, then open up another terminal, CD into programB, run the startB.bat file. I just want to have a single bat file that starts up both. I can kill the one command window to stop both processes.

My bat file is currently as follows:

```
set programdir=C:\ProgramA
CD /D %programdir%
@start /b cmd /c startA.bat
set programdir=C:\ProgramB
@start /b cmd /c startB.bat
```

The above just flat out does not work the way I expect.

Comment: Are you sure it runs StartB but nor StartA? I'd conclude the opposite...

Comment: Disregard my comment, looks like the programdir/root dir is messed up. It's showing that it can't find startA.bat, and cant find startB.bat. My guess is the directory setting is being weird, I don't think the code I have is working the way I expect it to.

Comment: The point is that you're carefully changing the current directory to `ProgramA`'s directory, then running `StartA` from that directory; then you attempt to run `StartB` without having changed the directory, so I'd conclude you *could* run `StartA`, but not `StartB`

Comment: Right, so my question is, given we have 2 different directories, how do I run both? Do have have to do some one line @start when I do the setting? Or is there some other way?

Comment: you may want to use `start` parameter `/D` (see `start /?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work actually:

```
@start "" /B %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\ProgramA\startA.bat"
@start "" /B %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\ProgramB\startB.bat"
```

It could be that both batch files are not good coded because of expecting that the directory of the batch file is the current directory on execution of the batch file without taking care of this requirement by having at top the command line `cd /D "%~dp0"` or even better `pushd "%~dp0"` or referencing other files in directory of batch file with `"%~dp0OtherFile"` instead of just `OtherFile`.

In this case it is necessary to set explicitly the current directory to directory of the batch file before starting the batch file in a separate command process running without opening a new console window.

```
@start "" /B /D"C:\ProgramA" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "startA.bat"
@start "" /B /D"C:\ProgramB" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "startB.bat"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `start /?`